# How to measure my elo with using deep fritz 14?

Tags: elo, fritz

I think I’ve heard deep fritz estimates elo and shows to user, but I don’t know how.

Comment: try this you get an *estimate* problem is the standard deviation is wide another problem is that there are fundamental flaws in the rating of chess players so at best it is a guide to strength and not nearly as accurate as people seem to think it is if you could play a couple hundred games against rated players both weaker and stronger but not a lot more than you then you could get a good estimate of your skill AT THAT TIME problem is people change over time. kids improve fast and their ratings are always behind their actual level. while doing that they take points from other players making th

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I would recommend trying to gauge your ELO from a computer software alone.  There may be a way to get some estimation, but I'm not confident about that.  Besides, the best way to get an accurate idea of how well you play is by playing people!  Go out there and play some chess!